# Don't execute org-mode links to executables

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I've managed to set up my `org-file-apps` mostly the way I want it, although one thing remains: I'd prefer if executable files were opened directly in Emacs since most of them are scripts that I'd like to edit instead of run.

My current settings are:

```
(setq org-file-apps
'(("\\.docx\\'" . default)
  ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
  ("\\.pdf\\'" . default)
  ("\\.log\\'" . emacs)
  (sh-mode . emacs) ; <-- didn't work, it detects the executable bit then runs
  (auto-mode . emacs)))
```

I was looking around for something along the lines of `executable-mode` or the like but came up short. Is there some other symbol to do this (I'm aware of the problem that it will open binaries in the editor but that seldom how I link)?

Comment: In `org-version` 9.0.5 `sh-mode` is none of the possible values of the file identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current settings the line `(sh-mode . emacs)` is not valid.
Documentation states that only following entries: `string`, `directory`, `remote`, `auto-mode`, `t` and `system` are allowed.
This means if your shell-scripts do not have a special filename pattern you have to work around.

**To work around you could:**
**A)** add, at the end of `org-file-apps` alist (after `(auto-mode . emacs)`), the line: `(t . emacs)`.
Then everything which drops to there will be loaded into emacs.
*But beware:* This means you have to catch other stuff, you never want loaded in emacs before this line.

**B)** misuse the groups feature. This is way more cool. Documentation states this:

> Regular expression which contains (non-shy) groups: Match links where the whole link, including "::", and anything after that, matches
> the regexp. In a custom command string, %1, %2, etc. are replaced with
> the parts of the link that were matched by the groups. For backwards
> compatibility, if a command string is given that does not use any of
> the group matches, this case is handled identically to the second one
> (i.e. match against file name only). In a custom lisp form, you can
> access the group matches with (match-string n link).
>
> Example: (".pdf::(\d+)'" . "evince -p %1 %s")
> to open [[file:document.pdf::5]] with evince at page 5.

Also it states that sexp are allowed as command:

> sexp  A Lisp form which will be evaluated.  The file path will
> be available in the Lisp variable `file'.

*So you could do:*

*1)* set your `org-file-apps` (adapt this to your needs):

```
(setq org-file-apps
'(("\\.log\\'" . emacs)
  (".*::\\(editme\\)\\'" . (my-find-file-wrapper file))))
```

*2)* define your own opening function:

```
(defun my-find-file-wrapper (f)
    (message "fooo")
    (find-file f))
```

*3)* write your links with following style `[[file:skriptfilename::editme]]`

*Note:* instead of using `my-find-file-wrapper` you could use a regular elisp function which eats the file parameter.

**Appendix:**
Of course if all your shell scripts have the extension `.sh`, you could just replace `(sh-mode . emacs)` with `("\\.sh\\'" . emacs)` . ;)

Comment: tested with org version 8.2.10

Comment: Nice! I'll try it out (second technique I think)

Comment: @JacobOscarson good you like it. The second technique took me a while from idea to a working setup. Is it solving your problem?

Comment: Works as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I intercept all files:

- without an extension
- filename only consists of alphanumeric and "_"

and refuse to open if target is a binary.

```el
(defun my/open-if-not-binary (path link)
  (let ((buf (find-file-noselect path)))
    (if (eq 'no-conversion (with-current-buffer buf buffer-file-coding-system))
        (progn (kill-buffer buf)
               (message "target is a binary file, add `C-u' if you insist"))
      (switch-to-buffer buf))))

(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("/[[:alnum:]/]+/[[:alnum:]_]+$" . my/open-if-not-binary))
```

refs: [detecting binary](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1opx6z/emacs_function_for_determining_whether_a_file_is/)